# Not quite sure how to use fread to store characters in c

Tags: c, fread

So I have the following struct

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fiona\\Desktop\\example.txt", "r");
struct packet{
     unsigned short block_num;
     unsigned short block_size;
     unsigned short crc;
     unsigned char *payload;
            };

//Create a dummy packet for testing 
struct packet chunk;        
    chunk.block_num = 0;
    chunk.block_size = 256;
    chunk.crc = 0x101001;
    chunk.payload = malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("block num = %d", chunk.block_num);
    printf("\nblock size = %d", chunk.block_size);
    printf("\ncrc = %d", chunk.crc);
    printf("\npayload = %c", chunk.payload);
```

I want to read the first 256 bytes of my example.txt and store it into payload but im not sure how to use the fread function to do that

I tried:

```
fread(chunk.payload, sizeof(char), 256, fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `fread()`

```
fread(chunk.payload, sizeof(char), 256, fp);
```

looks ok... but your `malloc()`

```
chunk.payload = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

does not.  You need to allocate space for *all* the characters, and (probably) a null char at the end... not just one character.  You'll also need to add the null character (probably).  Try:

```
chunk.payload = malloc(256 + 1);
chunk.payload[256] = '\0';
```

The null character at the end might not be needed if the data you're reading isn't meant to be treated as a null-terminated string, in which case you'll need to keep track of the length and just make sure not to access past the end of the data.

--

Also:

```
printf("\npayload = %c", chunk.payload);
```

..should be (if null-terminated):

```
printf("\npayload = %s", chunk.payload);
```

since you're printing a null-terminated string.

Comment: Ideally you should also check the return from `fread()` and possibly add the terminator early if it didn't read a full 256 chars.